# Fastest query to get the rank from stats

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the rank of a player from the DB. The problem is that the ORDER BY wouldn't just cut it.

I have a table of stats, each stat has an ID(unique), player ID and points.
I want to get the rank a certain player from the stats, where the rank is defined to be by the average of the points.

So if I have 2 players, one played 10 times with average of 5 points and the other 1 time with 4 points, the first player ranked 1 and the second 2.

The problem come in the size of the stats table. It has about 100,000 rows and about 20 col in each(more than just the points, I want to get it's rank in every possible thing, like the free throws made and more).

How to implement it in the fastest way with the 20 cols there are?
What I do for now, is get all of the averages for all of the players, than in PHP I check how many are better than the average of our player, and that is the rank.
But, the query itself takes around 10 seconds. And I do it more than once in one page.

I am adding the query that takes a lot of time, it is with teams so just imagine it is the same as players.

```
$p2pQuery = '100*avg(s.P2M/s.P2A)';
$p3pQuery = '100*avg(s.P3M/s.P3A)';
$ftpQuery = '100*avg(s.FTM/s.FTA)';
$effQuery = 'avg(s.P2M - s.P2A + s.P3M - s.P3A + s.FTM - s.FTA + s.TOT + s.AST + s.ST + s.FV + s.PTS - s.TO - s.CM)';

$whatWeWant = " avg(s.P2M) as P2M, avg(s.P2A) as P2A,  $p2pQuery as P2P,
    avg(s.P3M) as P3M, avg(s.P3A) as P3A,  $p3pQuery as P3P,
    avg(s.FTM) as FTM, avg(s.FTA) as FTA,  $ftpQuery as FTP,
    avg(s.OFFENSE) as OFFENSE, avg(s.DEF) as DEF, avg(s.TOT) as TOT, 
    avg(s.AST) as AST, avg(s.TO) as 'TO', avg(s.ST) as ST, avg(s.FV) as FV, avg(s.CM) as CM, avg(s.PTS) as PTS,
    $effQuery as EFF";

$db = dbConnect();
$allTeamsString = "SELECT t.ID as ID, $whatWeWant FROM teams as t, gamesstats as gs, stats as s
    WHERE gs.LeagueId = $ESCleague 
    AND gs.SeasonStart = $ESCseason
    AND t.ID <> $ESCteam
    AND ((gs.HomeTeamID = t.ID AND gs.HomeStat = s.ID) 
        OR (gs.VisitorTeamID = t.ID AND gs.VisitorStat = s.ID))
    GROUP BY t.ID";
$allTeamsQuery = MyQuery($allTeamsString);
$allTeams = resultSet2RowArray($allTeamsQuery, true);
mysql_close ($db);
```

The logic is. I get the average of each team in every single stat and for every stat I check the amount of teams from the query with a bigger value than what our team has.

Comment: Please show your query and your table indexes, as with the right indexes this shouldnt take 10 seconds Im sure.

Comment: Added the query, what do you mean the table indexes?

Comment: @BugFinder indexes useful only to find value. When DB need to calculate all existing values, indexes will not help so much. @Vadiklk, show your table structure, write full logic of calculating rank. As suggestion only: you can try to denormalize table and calculate some parts of rank when you insert new line, not only select.

Comment: @OZ_ depends on the query, hence a full picture is always useful. As also demonstrated by the actual query, initial question just implied average score per user, where as this is trying to do teams, and various other stats.

Comment: Players was a metaphore for the teams, I thought it would be more understandable.

Comment: @Vadiklk, what returns this query: SELECT count(*) FROM teams as t, gamesstats as gs, stats as s WHERE ((gs.HomeTeamID = t.ID AND gs.HomeStat = s.ID) OR (gs.VisitorTeamID = t.ID AND gs.VisitorStat = s.ID))

Comment: @Vadiklk, by the way if you use joins, indexes usually are important. Are primary and foreign keys indexed?

Comment: I use and ID as a primary index in all of the table. What are foreign keys? The select will return all of the stats of the games. That means for every game will return 2 stats, one for home and one for visitor. The count will be 7,000+.

Comment: @Vadiklk 7000+ rows is not much, so I posted an answer which in my opinion should solve your problem.

Comment: @Vadiklk by the way, foreign keys are columns which points to another table. So usually it's a good idea to add an index on these columns too.

Comment: @Vadiklk add EXPLAIN before the query, run it and post the results. This will help us to see if you use proper indexes. And this is the starting point of any query optimisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be a very good idea to add indexes on these 2 foreign keys:

```
ALTER TABLE `gamesstats` ADD INDEX `gs_index1` (`HomeTeamID` ASC, `HomeStat` ASC);
ALTER TABLE `gamesstats` ADD INDEX `gs_index2` (`VisitorTeamID` ASC, `VisitorStat` ASC);
```

Comment: Actually those indexes can't be used in the WHERE since there is OR condition between them. The indexes are needed for the joins, but the gs_index1 can't be used to join the "s" table.

Comment: @Darhazer No! Look: `(gs.HomeTeamID = t.ID AND gs.HomeStat = s.ID) 
        OR (gs.VisitorTeamID = t.ID AND gs.VisitorStat = s.ID)`. As you can see `OR` does not intersect indexes

Comment: The t table is joined on HomeTeamID or VisitorTeamID, and the s table is joined on HomeStat OR VisitorStat. This of course is a bet, and only explain can show if I am correct

Comment: @Darhazer You should think in other way.  You can split this select in two separate queries (one with `gs.HomeTeamID = t.ID AND gs.HomeStat = s.ID` and another with `gs.VisitorTeamID = t.ID AND gs.VisitorStat = s.ID`). Then you can use `UNION ALL` and get the the same result. MySQL optimizer should be clever enough to understand this.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't have a RANK function. I found a collection of MySQL recipes [here](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#460) for querying for rank under various conditions.

Comment: I've read it, but what about when I want it ranked based on averages?

Comment: I'd see whether the technique using a temporary table can be adapted to your needs.